# DC motor, confusion in specification about Current

Tags: power-supply, current, dc-motor, load, calculation

So, I am trying to build a little robot mower, and getting all parts. So I recently buyed two DC 12V motors, here is the specs:

[image: dc geared motor 12v specs]

Now I am trying to calculate how big or which battery should I use, and here is my confusion:

Why **unload current** is way bigger than **rated current** inside specs?

And which one should I use in calculation for a battery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a few google searches it looks to be a poorly documented chinese motor. *IMHO* it means "stall current" but poorly translated.

Comment: You can expect a mower to stall when it encounters long grass or junk, so the battery should be rated to handle the stall current short term (peak current) though the continuous current rating can be lower.

Comment: If it is really stall current, that means I should find H Bridge that can perform 40A short term, and a battery to support it.